# Datetime Parse Query

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime

I'm trying to catch data between two dates in database.

When I try to execute this query in SQL Server Management Studio, it's working fine.

```
SELECT
    cha_tarihi
FROM
    CARI_HESAP_HAREKETLERI
WHERE
    ha_tarihi BETWEEN '2016-02-10' AND '2016-10-10';
```

But when I want to try in my C# project, it's not working, not returning any data from database.

I'm trying about two hours please help what is the problem?

Query in my C# project

```
 var editeddate = DateTime.ParseExact(
    dateEdit1.EditValue.ToString(),
    "d.M.yyyy hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
);

var editeddate2 = DateTime.ParseExact(
    dateEdit2.EditValue.ToString(),
    "d.M.yyyy hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
);

query.Sql =
    @"select cha_tarihi from CARI_HESAP_HAREKETLERI where cha_tarihi between '" +
    editeddate.ToString( "yyyy-MM-dd" ) +
    "' AND '" +
    editeddate2.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") +
    "'";
```

Comment: Stop building your SQL like that. Use parameterized queries instead. That may or may not be the problem, but it's definitely the first thing to do.

Comment: Keyword `SQL Injection`

Comment: Why are you formatting the date twice?   Not quite sure what the result will be.    See what is in editeddate (which is already a string) .toString("yyyy-MM-dd").

Comment: Devexpress datetime return another format ddont accept from query because of this i tried parse
and they are different dates first start date second end date

Comment: I think the answer is simple, `editeddate` and `editeddate2` do not contain the values that you think they contain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var sql = @"SELECT cha_tarihi 
            FROM   CARI_HESAP_HAREKETLERI 
            WHERE  cha_tarihi BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate";

var command = new SqlCommand(sql, {your connection});

// You have EditValue.ToString() - what is the type of this value?
// You maybe be able to skip the DateTime.Parse
command.Parameters.Add("@startdate", SqlDbType.DateTime2)
                  .Value = DateTime.Parse(dateEdit1.EditValue)
                                   .ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"); 
command.Parameters.Add("@enddate", SqlDbType.DateTime2)
                  .Value = DateTime.Parse(dateEdit2.EditValue)
                                   .ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Comment: You need to use the `@` prefix for the parameters in your SQL string (instead of `$`) ....